# Add extra column and value to excel file before sending to SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I am uploading an Excel file and inserting the data into SQL Server. But the issues is that before I send the Excel data to SQL Server, I want to add an extra column and value before sending.

Here is the code I tried:

```
using (OleDbConnection exel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    exel_con.Open();
    string sheet1 = exel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[12] { new DataColumn("Full Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Email Address", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("ID Type",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("ID Number", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Gender",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Date of Birth", typeof(DateTime)),
                    new DataColumn("Nationality",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Married Status", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Join Date", typeof(DateTime)),
                    new DataColumn("Position",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Salary/Wages Frequency", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Salary/Wages Amount",typeof(int))
    });

    // Where I tried to add new column
    dtExcelData.Columns.Add("AdminId", typeof(int));

    foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
    {
        // Where I tried to add new value to the column.
        row["AdminId"] = 1;
    }

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", exel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }

    exel_con.Close();

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollSystem"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            // Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Employee";

            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("AdminId", "AdminId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Full Name", "FullName");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Email Address", "Email");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID Type", "IdType");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID Number", "IdNumber");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Gender", "Gender");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date of Birth", "DateOfBirth");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nationality", "Nationality");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Married Status", "MaritalStatus");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Join Date", "JoinDate");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Position", "Position");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary/Wages Frequency", "SalaryFrequency");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary/Wages Amount", "SalaryAmount");

            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please any help to solve this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you tried?   If you got an error, what was the exact error message?

Comment: @TabAlleman I did not get any error message but the AdminId I though I inserted to the datatable was inserting null to my database

Comment: Ok then, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the values to the new column AFTER you `Fill()` the DataTable.  Until you fill it, it doesn't have any rows to loop through.

In fact, you should add the new column after you fill the DataTable since you are going to use SELECT * to fill it, and therefore the columns in the Excel have to match the columns in the DataTable.

So, fill the DataTable first.   Then add the new column and values.

Comment: I am getting an error -  The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination I have added two new columns

Comment: You should open a new question so you can add details and show your code.  There are too many possible reasons for me to guess what's causing your error.